# Buffered Video in JQuery throws Javascript error in IE9 and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

My JQuery API for skin & functionality customization of html5 video works fine in all browsers.

But IE9 and Opera throws one error message when the buffered value of the video get called. The coding is:

```
var buffertime = $hdVideo[0].buffered.end(0);
```

**The Error message in Opera is:**

Uncaught exception: [object DOMException]
Error thrown at line 208, column 16 in () in localhost/hd-videos/version1.0.d/scripts/hd-video.js:
    var buffertime = $hdVideo[0].buffered.end(0);
called from line 55, column 294 in (a) in localhost/hd-videos/version1.0.d/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js:
    i=i.handler.apply(this,arguments);
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 49, column 569 in () in localhost/hd-videos/version1.0.d/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js:
    return typeof c!=="undefined"&&!c.event.triggered?c.event.handle.apply(o.elem,arguments):w

**In IE9:**

SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
hd-video.js, line 208 character 17

What is the right way to get buffered value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check 2 things:

1. Is buffered available (older browsers do not support the buffered property)
2. The length of the buffered property

   var buffertime = ($hdVideo[0].buffered && $hdVideo[0].buffered.length) ? $hdVideo[0].buffered.end(0) || 0;//add 0 or $hdVideo[0].duration

Comment: Your first option is right...
Opera & IE9 don't support buffered()